# How to show places with coordinates and multilanguage labels in Wikidata SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to retrieve a list of points of interests of a given class or subclass (museum, skyscraper, etc.) in a given city and to display for each of them:

- The list of translated labels in all known languages in a single row (for eg. "Statue of Liberty[en]___Freiheitsstatue[de]___Statua della libertà[it]")
- The latitude and longitude
- Other properties (for example the height of skyscrapers, if any)

What I did so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?lbl; separator='___') AS ?label) WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P131* wd:Q61 .
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q33506 .
  ?item rdfs:label ?l .
  BIND(CONCAT(STR(?l), ' (', LANG(?l), ')') AS ?lbl)
}
GROUP BY ?item
```

[View on Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3Flbl%3B%20separator%3D%27___%27%29%20AS%20%3Flabel%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP131%2a%20wd%3AQ61%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ33506%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fl%20.%0A%20%20BIND%28CONCAT%28STR%28%3Fl%29%2C%20%27%20%28%27%2C%20LANG%28%3Fl%29%2C%20%27%29%27%29%20AS%20%3Flbl%29%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem)

How can I add the other info?

Comment: By "other properties" you mean anything else about POI? And do you really need anything in a single row? Like you did for the labels.

Comment: Yes, if possible I would like to show them in a single row, like I did with the labels. By other properties I mean some properties that I will select to show. I just don't know how to query them in order to show in a separate column.

Comment: Well, it's just to add another triple pattern, e.g. for a property `wdt:P11` you just add `?item wdt:P11 ?valP11 .`. But if the property has multiple values, you need to add `GROUP_CONCAT` again, otherwise, you get multiple rows for the same item, with each row showing another value of the property.